# Difference between Get-Unique and select-object -unique

Tags: powershell, csv, powershell-4.0

Using PowerShell, I import csv-data from file via "import-csv" into the object $csvList. This csv-data has a column called Benutzer. When doing something like this:

```
$csvList | %{$_.Benutzer} | select-object -unique
```

there is nothing special: as expected, the unique entries in Benutzer are returned, which are around 10 items. However,

```
$csvList | %{$_.Benutzer} | get-unique -asstring
```

or

```
$csvList | Group($_.Benutzer)
```

seem to treat each entry as unqiue, i.e. the entire array of 260 Benutzer is returned in case of get-unique and 260 groups are created in case of the group statement.
I am using PowerShell 4.0.

Any idea what is going on here is appreciated...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From `Get-Unique` help:

> The Get-Unique cmdlet compares each item in a *sorted list*...

`Select-Object -Unique` does not require objects to be pre-sorted.

Example:

```
PS> 9,8,9,8 | Get-Unique -AsString
9
8
9
8
```

Example:

```
PS> 9,8,9,8 | Sort-Object -Unique
8
9
```

As for `Group-Object`, the syntax of the command should be different, replace `($_.Benutzer)` with the property name `Benutzer`:

```
$csvList | Group-Object Benutzer
```